# Grab text of first row of column with last data value

Tags: google-sheets

Essentially, I want the values in column D to be the value of the header row of the column with the last data value.

For example, if H27 is the last cell with data in row 27, I want D27 to be the text value of H1.

There will be blank values in each row.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following formula in `D2`.

### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(D2:D) = QUERY({H2:H, ROW(H2:H)},"SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 <> '' ORDER BY Col2 DESC LIMIT 1"), H1, ""))
```

It will automatically show the title of the header in column H in the last entry of column H, in column D.

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach, which relies on using some character (backtick `` ` `` in my example) that is not contained in any header. I don't think I ever put backticks in any spreadsheets of mine but if you did, pick another character.

```
D2 =REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("`", FILTER(E$1:$1, LEN(E2:2))), "[^`]*$")
```

(and drag down the column D). Explanation:

1. `FILTER` selects the 1st row entries from the columns in which the 2nd row is nonempty (`LEN>0`)
2. `JOIN` joins these entries, separating them by backticks
3. `REGEXEXTRACT` extracts the part of string matching `` [^`]*$ ``, which is a regular expression saying: the longest substring at the end that does not contain backticks. This will be the header of the last column with nonempty 2nd row.

Comment: Instead of backticks, one might want to use some high-code Unicode character like I did [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80350/79865).

Answer (score 1):

Shorter (in D1 and copied down to suit):

```
=if(row()=match("zzzz",H:H),H$1,"")
```

[IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
[ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
[MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

Relies on `zzzz` not being found in ColumnH - if it is, use more `z`s.